# Deleting Records with Batch class and Platform Events

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, platform-event

I am trying to delete accounts using a batch class. I am firing platform events from the batch class, and handling the deletion logic platform event subscribed trigger, but not all account records are deleting - only 2 records are deleting.

```
global class accountDeletionBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query;
        query='Select id,name from account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> accs)
    {
        List<AccountEvent__e> aevents=new List<AccountEvent__e>();
        if(accs.size()>0)
        {
            for(Account acc:accs)
            {
                aevents.add(new AccountEvent__e(Event__c='DELETE',Id__c=acc.Id));
            }

            if(aevents.size()>0)
            {
                List<Database.SaveResult> results=EventBus.publish(aevents);
            }
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        accountDeletionBatchClass b=new accountDeletionBatchClass();
        database.executebatch(b);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
trigger AccountTrigger on AccountEvent__e (after insert) {
set<id> rids=new set<id>();
       for(AccountEvent__e r:Trigger.New)
       {
           if(r.Event__c=='DELETE')
           {
               rids.add(r.Id__c);
           }
       }

       List<Account> delids=[select id from account where id IN:rids];

       delete delids;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the LIMIT from your query. Every batch of 200 records will only delete a single record.

Also, you don't need to check for empty lists before you iterate over them/DML on them.

Here's the optimized version:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> accs) {
    List<AccountEvent__e> aevents=new List<AccountEvent__e>();
        for(Account acc:accs) {
            aevents.add(new AccountEvent__e(Event__c='DELETE',Id__c=acc.Id));
        }
        EventBus.publish(aevents);
    }
}
```

Comment: even though i removed limit i am not able to delete the record only one or two records are deleting

Comment: @SaiVinayManapuram You would need to do some debugging then. I see no reason why this shouldn't work, although I'm not sure why you're using a platform event to do the deletion to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. That DML delete statement was causing a problem if one record failed to delete, so I used `Database.delete(list,false)`